# Preserving HTML Formating when posting a status update

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm adding features to our in-house CMS, one of the requests is to be able to post content to the CMS and our Facebook page at the same time. I have the actual posting part working, however, the HTML tags that are embedded in the content do not render in the Facebook status.

I get something like:
    <p>hello world</p> instead of the rendered text.

Is there a format that I can convert the html tags to that will preserve at least the line and paragraph breaks?

Comment: _“Is there a format that I can convert the html tags to that will preserve at least the line and paragraph breaks?”_ – Yes. It’s called _plain text_.

Answer (score 1):

The API strips any and all HTML from status updates before rendering them. If you want to preserve line breaks, you encode them as you pass them, eg `%0A` for a line break

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&message=Hello%0AWorld!!!`